# wcf Configuration : Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

Tags: c#, wcf

I got this probleme while debbuging My wcf service :

Failed to add a service. Service metadata may not be accessible

My config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors >
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Serv.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="">
        <endpoint address=""  binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Serv.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
             <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/Serv/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>

    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  </configuration>
```

and My Contract :

```
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    void Register(string Name, string Email, string Phone, string Password);


    [OperationContract]
    void Reserve(int User_ID, int Table, DateTime Date);


    [OperationContract]
    DataTable Login(string Email, string Password);

    [OperationContract]
    string heck_Email(string Email);

    [OperationContract]
    DataTable Show_History(int User_ID);


    [OperationContract]
    List<Data.Product> Show_P();



    [OperationContract]
    Data.Login Log(string User, string Pass);
}
```

i tried to change my Config But it didnt work i still get the same error message help pls !

Comment: remove the `behaviorConfiguration=""`. `behaviorConfiguration` must be a valid service behavior configuration name.

Comment: Still Getting The Same Error !

Comment: I copied your config in my project, it's working fine.